# How to get the return value from an async method, stored in a Task variable

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I'm studying asynchronous programming on C# and I wrote this piece of code:

```
namespace CSharpThreading
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task taskA = MethodToBeCalledParallelly(100);
            Task taskB = MethodToBeCalledParallelly(200);
            Task taskC = MethodToBeCalledParallelly(300);

            int a = await taskA;
            int b = await taskB;
            int c = await taskC;
        }
   
        static async Task<int> MethodToBeCalledParallelly(int extraDelay)
        {
            int totalDelay = 3000 + (int)extraDelay;

            await Task.Delay(totalDelay);
            Console.WriteLine("I was called parallelly");

            return totalDelay;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is not compiling. What I'm trying to do is to get the return value from the method that I'm calling on the task. Obviously I'm doing something wrong. But I don't know what. Can someone point me the right direction?

Comment: what is the compiling error

Comment: Change your `Task` variable declarations to `Task<int>` (or just `var`) and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: I knew it should probably be a silly mistake. Thanks to everyone that answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Task to Task of int as shown below

```
namespace CSharpThreading
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task<int> taskA = MethodToBeCalledParallelly(100);
            Task<int> taskB = MethodToBeCalledParallelly(200);
            Task<int> taskC = MethodToBeCalledParallelly(300);

            int a = await taskA;
            int b = await taskB;
            int c = await taskC;
        }
   
        static async Task<int> MethodToBeCalledParallelly(int extraDelay)
        {
            int totalDelay = 3000 + (int)extraDelay;

            await Task.Delay(totalDelay);
            Console.WriteLine("I was called parallelly");

            return totalDelay;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify correct type for variables - either `Task<int>` or use [`var` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/declarations#implicitly-typed-local-variables) to leverage implicit typing:

```cs
Task<int> taskA = MethodToBeCalledParallelly(100);
Task<int> taskB = MethodToBeCalledParallelly(200);
// or var
var taskC = MethodToBeCalledParallelly(300);

int a = await taskA;
int b = await taskB;
int c = await taskC;
```

[`Task<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-7.0) inherits from [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0) so the `Task taskA = MethodToBeCalledParallelly(100);` variable declaration will work but `Task` does not expose any result so awaiting it will result in void return which can't be assigned to `int` variable.